# Warning about using a whole package of antd is not resolved with babel-import-plugin. Antd bug or incorect usage of babel import plugin?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

When I try make import like this in ant design with react

```
 import {UserOutlined, LockOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons'
```

I get next warning

```
"You are using a whole package of antd, please use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import 
to reduce app bundle size warning or what wrong with my babelrc?"
```

I try to fix it with bubble-import-plugin but it dont work
Maybe I use it wrong way?

*in client folder I have react app and in `package.json` -  babel blugin for import and also babelrc config with next settings

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["import", {"libraryName": "antd"}]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case was problem solved by upgrading to the new antd version - 4.14.0. Then the warning disappeared. Also check, if you have your .babelrc file in root of your project (the place, where is package.json file)

Comment: I was able to experiment with two react apps running  CRA v4. Installing babel-import plugin, did not remove the warning for project 1, until we upgraded to 4.16.1 from 4.11.2. In project 2, I just upgraded antd to 4.16.1, and the warning also went away, WITHOUT installing the plugin. Concerning...

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the issue at least in my case is that I was importing a component differently:

This cleared the warning:

`import { Layout } from "antd"`

This caused the warning to show:

`import { Layout } from "antd/lib"`

Answer (score 0):

I donw know how it works but and why and  design dont describe this on docs, but my solution has been found here
https://github.com/PW486/react-antd-boilerplate
just using  "react-app-rewired" when start app